# How can I restrict sales user in accessing my admin folder using PHP?

Tags: php, php-5.5

I have 2 different folders one for the Sales User and the Other is for the admin folder.

When the administrator login he/she don't have access in this url:

http://localhost/enye-web/sales

Comment: I mean when the sales user already login he/she cannot access http://localhost/enye-web/admin

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? How are you determining an admin from a sales user (userlevel in database?) ? Your question doesn't provide a lot of information on what you've tried to do.

Comment: I already created role_type for admin and sales user. The thing is when i login to sales account when I go directly to localhost/web/admin (this link is for accessing the path of my admin folder) I can see all the info of the admin.

Comment: Is there a way if the sales user dont have an access to my admin folder?

Comment: therefore you need to run a role check and redirect accordingly to the correct page.

Comment: Yes there is, `if ($user_role != 'admin') { //redirect elsewhere } `